# Mongodb connection error ( connection 0 to 127.0.0.1:27017 timed out)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

There are many questions for this issue. I looked almost all of them and tried to fix my connection error but I couldn't

This is my code

```
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;   
    var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mgdb";

    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {  
    if (err) throw err;  
    console.log("Database created!");  
    //db.close();  
 });
```

The code is super simple though.. The error has been thrown  and it says

**MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost;27017] on first connection [MongoError: connection 0 to localhost:27017 timed]**

I did as answers for similar questions but all didn't fix my problem. please help me fix this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that most of those questions would at least have a comment asking if mongodb is actually installed? Did you [actually install the database server?](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/) Or did you just install the npm package and expect things to work? The simple reason the connection times out is because there is nothing to connect to. So the server is either not running, or simply not installed.

Comment: If you're using antivirus- or firewall-software, it might be blocking those connections.

Comment: @NeilLunn I am new to Node.js so it might sound stupid but how can I check if the server is either not running or not installed?

Comment: One more thing I forgot to mention is that I don't know why but I sometimes got an error saying "connect econnrefused" as well...

Answer (score 1):

By default, socket connection time for MongoDB is 30 seconds. If any query/operation takes longer than this the connection is aborted and connection timeout error occurs.

**To solve the issue**: You should consider to increase the connectTimeoutMS & socketTimeoutMS & also poolSize settings as the config below.

MONGO_URI=mongodb://user:password@127.0.0.1:27017/dbname?keepAlive=true&poolSize=30&autoReconnect=true&socketTimeoutMS=360000&connectTimeoutMS=360000

Answer (score -1):

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mgdb", {
    server: {
      socketOptions: {
        connectTimeoutMS: 500
      }
    },function(err, db) {
       if (err) throw err;  
       console.log("Database created!");  
});
```

Comment: I tried your code and I had an error saying MongoClient is undefined. Like @NeilLunn said above, I am trying to do this only by installing the npm package of mongo using node.js command prompt. A reason I am getting this undefined error and timed out is because I did not install the database server?